# Switch is not Working in Jquery..!

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying, but switch is not working finally i exhaust, and putting Question over here i know that its childish, but please help me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nature_property").change(function(){
   var nature_property_id = $(".nature_property").val();

      switch(nature_property_id){
    case nature_property_id == 1:
          $("#appartment").css("display", "block"); 
        break;
    }

}); 

});
</script>
```

Comment: Switch is from JavaScript. Read about switch statements. You have basic mistake - `case 1:` not `case x == 1:`. It will be executed and x == 1 will return boolean value.

Comment: @Rolice: This is not a syntax error. It's certainly undesired, but not a syntax error. What happens is that `nature_property_id == 1` evaluates to either true or false, so `nature_property_id` is compared against true or false.

Comment: But i am selecting id from Drop down box

Comment: nature_property_id == 1, means that selected id is equal to 1 than do thi,

Comment: @FelixKling, yes it will not stop the execution possibly and its a normal statement, but in fact it ends in unexpected behaviour (ends up case true or false).

Comment: @EngrZardari: That's not how a `switch...case` statement works. It **automatically** compares the value in `switch(x)` with the value of each `case` statement. I recommend to read the MDN documentation about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch. The example should be pretty clear.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for good suggestion let me try again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Last code was not working because input value coming with string. Below is the changed code

```
$(".nature_property").change(function(){

   var nature_property_id = $(".nature_property").val();

      switch(nature_property_id){
          case '1':
              alert('visibile')
          $("#appartment").show(); 
        break;
    }

});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sDGh8/)

Comment: I have update the answer http://jsfiddle.net/sDGh8/

Answer (score 2):

Change to this:

```
$(".nature_property").change(function(){
   var nature_property_id = this.value; //<----get the current target value
   switch(nature_property_id){
     case '1': //<-----------------------change your case this way
        $("#appartment").css("display", "block"); 
        break;
   }
});
```

---

What seems to me is there are multiple dropdowns with same className so i think you should get the value in the current element's context with keyword `this`.

---

#### Update:

`case '1'` i changed the numeric value to a string value because all input elements have string values.

Comment: This would be better if you create a demo at [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @EngrZardari see the update as here `case '1'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change:

```
case nature_property_id == 1:
```

to:

```
case 1:
```